# PHP SQL query while mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm performing a query to a database using

```
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  function1
  function2
}
```

And I need to do additional queries to the database inside functions 1 and 2.

Inside the function I'm creating new connections to the database but the script is very slow.

What is the best approach in PHP to make queries while processing another query?

Comment: maybe pass the `$connection` to functions 1 and 2?

Comment: The best approach is not to ;) There's almost always a way to restructure your queries, or use some array function(s) in php if needed, to use the data you need from the first query in your latter queries, without doing it within that loop. I might be wrong but I think it's even a performance increase to store the results in array in that while, then do it in a foreach - not the right approach either way. Some more info on specifically what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful. I recently learned a lot about this scenario after working closely with a sql pro, hopefully I can pass it on

Comment: Only create the connection once. Process both queries while the connection is open. Then close the connection once. If you need the results from query 1 as part of query 2, just execute them one after another and use the response.

Comment: Unless the first query returns an enormous amount of data, you can fetch it all into an array, then loop over that array, and make additional queries inside the loop. But as @TCooper says, the ideal solution is to join all the queries into a single query.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible to join everything into a single query and so, based on the received comments, I have used the following solution:

```
$conn = $mysqli_connect(...)

function function1($args,$conn) {
    $f1_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

function function2($args,$conn) {
    $f2_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

$mainquery = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  function1
  function2
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

This greatly improved the execution time. Thank you!